# Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug FAILED (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

I have issue to run demo flutter project.

log verbose :

[image]

Comment: Have you tried checking your flutter version. Try using the latest stable version

Comment: yes, i used a latest stable version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to use command
`flutter clean`
and then `flutter run`

Answer (score 0):

The error might be due to the improper installation of SDK. There are several solutions as per below:

1) Invalid Cache and restart. (the common one)
2) Reinstall flutter SDK.
3) Change the gradle version with the available version of your machine.
4) Removing "android.enableR8=true" line from the android project's gradle.properties file.

Comment: i have tried the above solution, but still got the same error